# Requiring a file that is also a program with it's own option parser

Tags: ruby, require, optparse

My problem is: the required file intercepts the option parser.

I'm writing a ruby program in 3 files, one (connect.rb) that handles connection to a certain site, and another 2 (populate.rb and update.rb) that require the first one to collect data from that site.

connect.rb can be ran to configure and test the connection, as such:

```
$ruby connect.rb --adduser myuser -p 1234 --test
Created user myuser
Connecting as myuser...
Connection test OK
```

On the other hand, populate.rb has a 'require connect.rb' line, but it also can be ran and has it's own options.

It used to be that connect.rb had no options, and it all worked fine, but since I added options to connect.rb with optparse, the option parser in populate.rb and update.rb doesn't work anymore. If I run 'ruby populate.rb -h', it shows the options available to connect.rb, not the ones in populate.rb. If I use options that connect.rb accepts, like '-t', the option is executed as if in connect.rb. If I use options that connect.rb doesn't accept, but populate.rb should, it shows a "invalid option" error and exits.

Basically, I want connect.rb to behave differently when I run it solo from when I require it in another file. When I run it solo, I want it to accept options and do things; but when it's required in another file, I want just the methods to be available, and I want a different set of options.

Is that even possible? Is there a way to tell how it's been called, or some other way to prevent option interception? I'm using optparse in all my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved something similar to this is to check if the file is being run solo like this:

```
# connect.rb    

# wrap logic in a module
module Connect
  def self.run(args: ARGV)
    args # access to command line options
  end
end

# run if solo
Connect.run if $0 == __FILE__
```

In the last conditional `$0` is a Ruby global set to the name of the executed file and `__FILE__` is the name of the current file. If both are the same then you know the file is running solo i.e. `ruby connect.rb`.

With that setup you can run `connect.rb` solo and it'll work fine. Then, when you require it in your other file `populate.rb` You need to explicitly run it:

```
# popoulate.rb
require 'connect'
Connect.run ARGV.dup # dup the commandline options in case other files mutate them
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand what the last line does, though. Does it run the module anyway, passing the arguments along? What happens if I don't add this line?

Comment: This line? `Connect.run ARGV.dup` yes it runs the module passing in the commandline options. If you don't add this line then the connect module won't run if you require it from populate.rb

Answer (score 0):

Ok so while I was writing my question I realized I knew one answer!

Basically move the 'require connect.rb' line to *after* the options have been parsed. So my populate.rb is now like this:

```
require "optparse"
Version = 1.4

# Parses command line arguments
options = {}
optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
    # populate the options array according to the options
    ...
end

optparse.parse!

require "./connect_fb"

# start actual program
...
```

This works because I separated option parsing from the bulk of the code by storing the options in an array, and because connect.rb doesn't need to do anything if it's called without any options. I don't really understand why the options parser that is called first is the only one that works.

I feel unconfortable with a 'require' line so far from the head of the file, so I hope there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the solutions presented in previous answers, I came to a simple solution:

You can test wheater the file is being ran solo with

```
if $0 == __FILE__
```

so I put all the parsing into a if block like this:

```
# connect.rb
# code to be ran when required
...
class connect
    ....
end

# the following will only be executed if this script is ran solo
if $0 == __FILE__
    # code to be ran solo here
    ...
    # also parse options here
    options = {}
    optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
        ...
    end
    optparse.parse!
    # more code
    ...
 end
```

This solution is basically the barebones version of diego's answer.